# load tikz library from relative path

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, package-writing, tikzlibrary

I recently externalized some of my often used TikZ commands into a library. This is as simple as writing the commands to a dedicated file and naming it `tikzlibraryname.code.tex`. Then it can be included using `\usetikzlibrary{name}`.

But this only works if it is placed in the same directory as the file that includes it or resides at some globally known include path. Trying a relative path like `\usetikzlibrary{../name}` results in an error

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibrary../name.code.tex'.
```

`\input{../tikzlibraryname.code.tex}` would be a workaround. Using the proper command `\usetikzlibrary` should be preferred though.

Can a tikz library be loaded from a relative path?

Comment: Add the custom file and it's path to your `texmf`

Comment: The library is part of a project also for others to access. I want to avoid directing everyone to move the file into their local texmf directory.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary` simply adds `tikzlibrary` in front of the arguments separated by `,`. Those files are supposed to be found by TeX. We could patch `\usetikzlibrary` to test for a `.` or a `/` at the start of the filename and parse the string so that it does `../tikzlibraryname.code.tex` but that fix needs to be able to be found by TeX or placed directly in the document. If the user changes the placement of the `tikzlibraryname.code.tex` outside of a path that can be found by TeX they might just be better off to use `\input`? (So the answer would be "No.")

Comment: @XZS: Hardcoding paths is _wrong_.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I am open to better alternatives. How could I place the file avoiding hardcoded paths? It is used in only one project, but in many documents of this project.

Comment: Why not package your "often used TikZ commands" in a .sty file instead? That would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the definition of `\usetikzlibrary`

```
\def\usetikzlibrary{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\use@tikzlibrary}{\use@@tikzlibrary}}%}
\def\use@tikzlibrary[#1]{\use@@tikzlibrary{#1}}
\def\use@@tikzlibrary#1{%
  \edef\pgf@list{#1}%
  \pgfutil@for\pgf@temp:=\pgf@list\do{%
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@spdef\expandafter\pgf@temp\expandafter{\pgf@temp}%
    \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
    \else
      \expandafter\ifx\csname tikz@library@\pgf@temp @loaded\endcsname\relax%
      \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname tikz@library@\pgf@temp @loaded\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
      \expandafter\edef\csname tikz@library@#1@atcode\endcsname{\the\catcode`\@}
      \expandafter\edef\csname tikz@library@#1@barcode\endcsname{\the\catcode`\|}
      \expandafter\edef\csname tikz@library@#1@dollarcode\endcsname{\the\catcode`\$}
      \catcode`\@=11
      \catcode`\|=12
      \catcode`\$=3
      \pgfutil@InputIfFileExists{tikzlibrary\pgf@temp.code.tex}{}{
        \pgfutil@IfFileExists{pgflibrary\pgf@temp.code.tex}{%
          \expandafter\usepgflibrary\expandafter{\pgf@temp}%
        }{%
          \tikzerror{I did not find the tikz library
            '\pgf@temp'. I looked for files named
            tikzlibrary\pgf@temp.code.tex and
            pgflibrary\pgf@temp.code.tex, but neither
            could be found in the current texmf trees.}
        }}%
      \catcode`\@=\csname tikz@library@#1@atcode\endcsname
      \catcode`\|=\csname tikz@library@#1@barcode\endcsname
      \catcode`\$=\csname tikz@library@#1@dollarcode\endcsname
      \fi%
    \fi
  }%
}
```

Notice that `\usetikzlibrary[fpu]` is just an alternative to `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}`. It does not eat options.

From the definition you can see that `\usetikzlibrary` takes cares of the following

- Check if the library is loaded. Some library can only be loaded once.
- Remember the catcode of sensitive characters `@`, `|`, and `$`. This allows you to use `\tikzlibrary` almost anywhere. In face, you can use it inside a `tikzpicture`.
- Test if the file exists. If so, input it.

The definition of the last check is

```
\def\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists#1#2#3{\pgfutil@IfFileExists{#1}
    {\input #1\relax#2}
    {#3}}%
```

you can modify its definition by

```
\def\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists#1#2#3{\pgfutil@IfFileExists{\tikz@library@directory #1}
    {\input \tikz@library@directory #1\relax#2}
    {#3}}%
```

with customized `\tikz@library@directory`.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary[fpu]` is for context if I remember correctly

Comment: @percusse Almost forgot ConTeXt. Yes, it definitely is. As the manual suggests.